# Virtual NSScreen

Tags: macos, virtual, nswindow

I am looking for a way to have an app show up as a second screen. A virtual `NSScreen` is the best way I can think to describe it.

The idea is to be able to have multiple connected monitors and my `MacOS` app would draw an `NSWindow` over over the combined size of the monitors to create one big `NSWindow`

Then users would be able to full screen their applications inside that `NSWindow` or `NSScreen`

I would like to write this in swift but I can work with Objective C